# criar e escrever com plugin cordova file ionic

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic3, ionic2

estou tentando escrever em um arquivo usando o file do cordova, como não posso escrever direto no assets (que é somente leitura), movo o arquivo e tento escrever, porém cai no catch erro2.

```js
 this.file.copyFile(this.file.applicationDirectory + '/www/assets/', 'catalogo.txt', 
    this.file.applicationStorageDirectory, 'catalogo.txt')
    .catch(e => window.alert('erro1'));


    this.file.writeFile(this.file.applicationStorageDirectory,"catalogo.txt",
    'escrita no arquivo????', {append: true})
    .catch(e => window.alert('erro2'));
```